# SAS 9.2 informat Z

Tags: sas, informat

I have a code that completes without errors in SAS EG 4.3 but encounters an error when run in LSF Flow Manager.

ERROR: The informat Z was not found or could not be loaded.

What could be the problem?

Thanks!

---

Answer (score 0):

There is no informat Zw.d.  Zw.d is only a format.  This is because w.d and Zw.d as informats would be identical.

Informat is instructions to convert a text string to a number.  So the instructions for converting "5.32" to 5.32 and the instructions for converting "05.32" to 5.32 would be the same, wouldn't they - just read it as number.  Hence, no Zw.d.

You likely have an input statement somewhere that reads,

```
x=input(y,Z5.);
```

You just need to make that

```
x=input(y,5.);
```

If you want X to then be formatted with Zw.d, then add a format statement after that.

Comment: That said, I am of the opinion SAS should probably create Zw.d informat as a synonym for w.d (like COMMAw.d and DOLLARw.d are synonyms, pointing to the same informat).  It would take a lot of headaches away from newer programmers, at least until they asked why x wasn't formatted properly :)